# Is possible to set width for icon in Android 12 Splash screens API

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I want to display app icon (120dpx120dp) in `SplashScreen`. I am using [Splash screens](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen#suspend-drawing) but it display bigger than 120dp. For any vector, it always bigger than 120dp.
After screenshot and calculate by Paint tool, I see that the app icon size in my device (Pixel 4XL) is ~ 160dp. So, if I add a padding 20dp to my app icon, on my Pixel 4XL device, the app icon will look like 120dpx120dp. But I don't know if it work in other device or not?

Answer (score 17):

In version `1.0.0-alpha02`, splash screen icon size is set to `288dp`. If you want to make icon smaller, you can add scale to your vector drawable. Something like this:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="48"
    >
    <group
        android:pivotX="24"
        android:pivotY="24"
        android:scaleX="0.25"
        android:scaleY="0.25"
        >
        <path
            ...
            />
        <path
            ...
            />
    </group>
</vector>
```

This would resize your splash screen icon to `72dp`.

Comment: when using branding icon via android:windowSplashScreenBrandingImage, scaling logic is the same but icon size is 200dp x 80dp, might be helpful

Comment: I find that devices have different splash screen icon size: one has 144dp, another has 288dp, another has 432dp

Comment: Is it possible to make the icon bigger? I find the sizes specified in the Android documentation to be very creatively limiting

Comment: Using scaleX and scaleY leads to different icon sizes on different devices, e. g. Samsung devices show a lot smaller icon than the emulator.

Comment: Where do I make this change? @Marek

Comment: @masewo I've run into the same issue as you (Samsung Galaxy S21 shows the splash icon a lot smaller than other devices), were you able to solve this problem? If so, can you please share your approach?

Comment: @ARandomAndroidDev Sadly no. I ended up making it pixel perfect just for Samsung devices, so in my case of my Flutter application this was the result: `<group
        android:scaleX="0.3765"
        android:scaleY="0.3765"
        android:translateX="31.50"
        android:translateY="31.50">`